Security concerns regarding Outbound Messages and Certificates
We're looking to implement an outbound integration from Salesforce to an external application that our company built.
Reading through the documentation about Outbound Messages, Salesforce mentioned that we can validate the identity through a Certificate.

If the configuration of your application (endpoint) server's SSL/TLS allows, validate the identity of the Salesforce server when it takes the role of a client to your server, using the Salesforce client certificate. For instructions to download the certificate, see Downloading the Salesforce Client Certificate

My question, is the Salesforce Certificate generated from each organization actually unique?
If it's not, what should be recommended to make sure that the outbound messages are actually coming from our organization?
Edit: I think part of the concern is someone from this similar thread mentioned that they generated a cert from 2 of their production orgs and it was the same cert: Outbound Message Security and Validation
We unfortunately don't have a Premier support plan so when we asked the same question from support, they weren't able to help us...

Outbound messages are not a good idea: see https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration for why and other options.

@identigral, Thank you so much! we reviewed the article you shared and have decided to move away from Outbound Messages and considered using Named Credentials + External Services instead. This seems like the better and more secure way to implement what we wanted.
